# How to split $(MAKECMDGOALS) by whitespace

Tags: java, awk, makefile

There is probably a better way to do this (and if there is please let me know), but I'm trying *make* it so that I don't have to type so much every time I want to compile and run my programs. I'll probably receive some comments about using a Makefile to compile and run my Java programs and that's fine. If I was actually developing Java applications, I would use an IDE. This is just for a class assignment.

I'm trying to pass my arguments from the command line to my Makefile.
Say I want to run this command:

> `java Driver -n $(arg1) -h $(arg2)`

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work

> arg1 = `echo $(MAKECMDGOALS) | awk {$$1}`

Ideally, all I would have to type is `make 1 2` and this would run `java Driver -n 1 -h 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ***really*** contrary to how Make is supposed to work. But if you insist, here it is:

```
arg1 := $(word 1,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
arg2 := $(word 2,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

null:
    java Driver -n $(arg1) -h $(arg2)

%:null
    @:
```

Comment: Could you explain how make is supposed to work? Or what exactly do you mean? I've always just used make for easy compilation and running my programs. Isn't a Makefile just the execution of a bunch of commands? @Beta

Comment: @J-Win: The plain arguments to Make are supposed to be target names, not parameters of other kinds. The syntax for passing parameters is `make arg1=1 arg2`, and if you want `make 1 2` to have the same effect (to save typing), then you get a weird makefile like the one I wrote above.

Comment: Makes sense. I think I'll just suck it up and do that instead